# Page does not work after published with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have an application that works perfectly in the local host, but when I publish it to a remote server I have a problem. I can see the page published that seems fine, but when I click "SAVE" it goes to a blank page and nothing happens.

What could I be missing?

I do not know what kind of information about the application that I could provide here to help to find a solution.

Comment: Could be error at "SAVE" function. Add try catch to your "SAVE" function and return another view on catch. And can you try to run it with Release mode? Could be anything I can not be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change in the Web.config and worked.

This was before:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Now, what worked:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```